# How do I access data from other files in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, function

I am trying to build a shopping cart page that calculates "total" by multiplying the "price" of a product by the "quantity" of a product. These values are located within different files than the shopping cart.

I have for example, my price element saved in UploadProductPage.js:

```
 const variables = {
      writer: props.user.userData._id,
      title: TitleValue,
      description: DescriptionValue,
      price: PriceValue,
      images: Images,
      continents: ContinentValue,
    };
    
    props.history.push({
      pathname: "/user/cart",
      state: {
        data: variables,
      }, 
    });
```

And I have quantity in userCardBlock.js:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    quantity: 1,
    price: "",
    deleteData: false,
  });
```

My CartPage.js file should contain a function that multiplies price by quantity. But I am not sure how to do it. My original attempt looked like:

```
const calculateTotal = props.price * props.state.quantity
```

Can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this case you may need to use some state management solution like [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start), [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), etc...

But if you don't want to go that way, maybe you can try to retrieve the data in a parent component and pass it whole through props.

In any case, please try to add a example code of a functional piece of code involving your question.